# SQL - SELECT registros que aparecían en una fecha anterior a la de hoy, y hoy ya no aparecen

Tags: sql, select, join

Tengo una tabla donde se meten un conjunto de solicitudes.

Cada día se actualiza esa tabla y se meten todas las solicitudes que estén pendientes por resolver. 
Por lo que si en la fecha más actual ya no sale una solicitud, significa que está resuelta.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Verde**: Solicitudes de ayer resueltas (Estas son las que quiero obtener). Sabemos que está resuelta porqué aparece el dia 25, pero no aparece en los datos insertados el dia 26.

**Rojo**: Solicitudes de ayer que se repiten hoy.

**Amarillo**: Solicitudes nuevas de hoy.

Que consulta SQL puedo usar para obtener las solicitudes en verde? Mi primera idea es hacer un JOIN de la misma tabla, pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Debes poner la estructura de tu tabla, no sabemos que determina el color. ¿Cómo se que una solicitud está resuelta?

Comment: Porque no aparece en los datos insertados el dia de hoy. Las que estan resueltas són las que aparecen en una fecha anterior pero no aparecen en la fecha actual

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a todos por la ayuda! Al final la he resuelto asi:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (select * from paginaweb_auxiliares.gdt_mensaj_parada_contrata_detalle_shell where FECHA_INSERCION < CURDATE()) A
LEFT JOIN(select* from paginaweb_auxiliares.gdt_mensaj_parada_contrata_detalle_shell where FECHA_INSERCION >= CURDATE()) B
ON A.solicitud = B.solicitud WHERE B.solicitud is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Las solicitudes resueltas las puedes obtener con esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM solicitudes
  WHERE solicitud NOT IN (
    SELECT solicitud FROM solicitudes
      WHERE fecha=DATE(NOW())
  );
```

Para comprobarlo, puedes utilizar este dataset de pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE solicitudes(
  solicitud int,
  fecha date
  );
INSERT INTO solicitudes (solicitud, fecha) VALUES
  (8,'2020-03-26'),
  (7,'2020-03-26'),
  (6,'2020-03-26'),
  (5,'2020-03-26'),
  (4,'2020-03-26'),
  (5,'2020-03-25'),
  (4,'2020-03-25'),
  (3,'2020-03-25'),
  (2,'2020-03-25'),
  (1,'2020-03-25');
```

Amplío la respuesta con las solicitudes en *rojo*:

```
SELECT * FROM solicitudes WHERE solicitud IN (
  SELECT solicitud FROM solicitudes
    WHERE fecha=DATE(NOW()) AND solicitud IN (
      SELECT solicitud FROM solicitudes
        WHERE fecha=(DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY))
    )
  );
```

Y en *amarillo*:

```
SELECT * FROM solicitudes
  WHERE fecha=DATE(NOW()) AND solicitud NOT IN (
    SELECT solicitud FROM solicitudes
      WHERE fecha=(DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  );
```

Por favor, deja en los comentarios cualquier duda para poder ampliar la respuesta de la mejor forma posible.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener las solicitudes de ayer que no están hoy, sean las solicitudes de ayer `sa` y las solicitudes de hoy `sh`:

```
SELECT sa.id, sa.fecha
  FROM solicitudes sa
    LEFT JOIN solicitudes sh
      ON    sh.id = sa.id
        AND sh.fecha = sa.fecha+interval 1 day
  WHERE sa.fecha = '2020-03-25'
    AND sh.id is null
```

- `LEFT JOIN` para que traiga el registro aunque no se cumpla la relación.
- `sh.id is null` es precisamente para obtener los registros que no están hoy.